# Issues with AWS lambda proxy integration

Tags: aws-lambda, yaml, aws-api-gateway

I have an AWS API Gateway endpoint that uses lambda proxy integration to retrieve data from an AWS RDS instance.

I use a yaml file to re-deploy the api, Once the API is re-deployed, The endpoint, illustrated above, throws an "Internal Server Error" every time I re-deploy the api.

The error goes off if I uncheck and then check the lambda proxy integration option/tick-box on the endpoint. This manual step is cumbersome and extremely unintuitive and can raise serious production issues.

Anyone facing similar issue know how to solve it without the additional "unchecking and checking" (manual) step?
What change in YAML can solve this problem ?

Comment: Also check whether it still works if you change name of lambda in API gateway and again rename it to old one.

Comment: I would expect that unchecking and rechecking is also setting or clearing some other field that is initially populatee incorrectly.

Answer (score 0):

Under your `AWS::ApiGateway::Method` resource, make your `Integration.Type` as `AWS_PROXY`

https://docs.aws.amazon.com/apigateway/api-reference/resource/integration/#type